# Android studio background banner color

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I can't manage to change the color of the banner background if the banner is not activated.
I think ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar might be responsible for default background color, but I can't find this part in styles.

[app_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWnF0.jpg) .
.
[andorid_studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIrhO.jpg)

I wish this background had a value of "@color/primary_color"

this is the code of this activity below:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.webkul.mobikul_cs_cart.view.RevealBackgroundView
        android:id="@+id/vRevealBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/subcategory_banner_appbaselayout_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/banner_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@color/primary_color"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:tabTextColor="#CCCCCC" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: What did you mean by "banner background" ?

Comment: When I add an image from the platform then there's an image, but when there's no image I wish to have a different color then it is now.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to change the background colour of CollapsingToolbarLayout. So why don't you do it?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how and where in code should I.

Comment: can you help me with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Using XML,

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      ...
      app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Programmatically,

```
collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

When your CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed its' colour will be changed to app's primary colour.